# Хочу создать программу для разархивирования rar архивов

Tags: python, rar

Хочу создать программу для разархивирования rar архивов. Знаю, что есть готовые решения, но не одно из них мне в полной мере не подошло. С чего стоит начать штурм rar формата? До этого никогда не занимался чем-то подобным. Что вообще в подобных ситуациях нужно делать? Поделитесь опытом.

Comment: [В подобных ситуациях надо гуглить](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614467/how-can-unrar-a-file-with-python)

Comment: [1](https://pypi.org/project/unrar/), [2](https://pypi.org/project/rarfile/)

Comment: @Victor says Reinstate Monica я же говорю, требуется именно самодельное решение.

Comment: Во-первых стоило бы указать, чем существующие решения не подошли. Во-вторых, исходный код утилиты unrar: https://github.com/pmachapman/unrar

Comment: Для этого Вам предстоит изучить сигнатуру, заголовки и формат `.rar`. А затем по каждому байту (а может даже и биту) пробегаться и делать какие-то шаги согласно спецификации формата для извлечения содержимого архива. Для "лайт" версии всего этого попробуйте самостоятельно решить [этот](https://training.hackerdom.ru/tasks/open/3/) таск из набора тасков группы HACKERDOM для подготовки к соревнованиям по CTF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю стоит начать с консольной утилиты, которая распаковывает 1 файл.

Вы можете скачать исходник unRAR c [официального сайта](https://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm).